# write a control by keyboard event

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

I want to write using javascript in an HTML input element using keyboard events.
In the HTML I have:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="myname" value='XX--'>
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm in a test phase so in the console i write:

```
let evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',
{code: 'Space', key: ' ', keyCode: 32, which: 32, bubbles: true, view: window});
```

and then:

```
document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Of course, first I click inside the text of the control to focus there.
The event seems to arrive at control but the character (space) is not written. I have even tried to use both `keydown` and `keyup` events in succession to no avail.

The thing is that I don't want to add event listeners. The real target is a text editor (Monaco editor) and I will not modify it. I need to write in the editor and I also want the event to go through its onKeyDown event handler. That's why I want to simulate a keyboard as realistic as possible.

I use currently Chrome but would be nice to have something that works for other browsers as well (Firefox, IE, etc).

Comment: Is that even a valid constructor for KeyboardEvent? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: Also in the aforementioned documentation, "Manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself."

Comment: ^^ That.  Events are handled by event handlers, so if you have no event handlers then dispatching events will have no effect.

Comment: @RyanWilson
Is it the isTrusted member of the event? I know is readOnly but can I clone the event but making isTrusted = true?